# Grades criadas automaticamente quando outras estiverem cheias

Tags: php, html

estou criando um pequeno website para meus amigos se divertirem em alguns sorteios. Basicamente o que tenho em mente é o seguinte:

Vou especificar no banco de dados quantas grades tem que haver rolando no site. Essas grades são basicamente vagas para os usuários entrarem em uma "rifa".
Então temos por exemplo 3 grades, uma que custa 10 pontos cada vaga outra que custa 20 e outra que custa 30. Isso será especificado no banco de dados e o usuário clica na vaga desejada para entrar na "rifa". Quando todas as vagas forem preenchidas o sorteio acontecerá no random.org.

O que preciso saber é como mantenho o próprio site recriando essas rifas quando elas terminarem. Por exemplo, a rifa de 10 pontos fechou e foi sorteada, outra rifa de 10 pontos se abre e assim com os outros valores também.
Pensei em algo que verifique no banco de dados o tempo todo mas sei isso não é bem a melhor solução, preciso saber o que fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crie uma tabela RIFA com os campos:

```
valor //10, 20 ou 30
idComprador //identifica o usuário por um id vindo de outra tabela (para evitar problemas com usuários com nomes iguais)
vendida //campo boolean
```

crie quantas rifas desejar de cada uma (digamos 30)

sempre que carregar a página faça algo semelhante ao código abaixo:

```
select count(*) from rifa where vendida = false and valor = 10; //pega o total de rifas sem vender

if (resultado == 0) //se nao tiver mais rifas para vender
{
    //comando que cria mais rifas
}
```

esse código é só para você usar como base pra criar o seu

Comment: Opa, obrigado mano. Não tinha pensado nisso e desse jeito vai dar certo. Vlw mesmo